# Dynamic field population VBA

Tags: vba, excel

I have written a script that simplifies a spreadsheet, but I need help with dynamically populating fields. The current format of the spreadsheet has inconsistent spacing so it is difficult to put together and if then statement that populates only populates subsections of a document.

I have attached an [image] of the way the document looks.

What I am trying to do is populate the Highlighted fields on the left based on the highlighted field on the right. e.g. (When Field "F3" populated - If "2012" and "092000" then populate BBFY with "2012" from cell "F2" in cells "A4" to "A11" Stop at last BOC number".) Start same process at next process with next group of data. Then if there is new data for the BOC name 2013 092300, fill in the corresponding information based on that information.

I am just having trouble trying to identify the correct calls to many changes are making it difficult to tell the code to change values based on new parameters. As you can see the highlighted values in F change and thus change the related information below. I have blocked out where I am trying to start up this section of the code.

The code I have so far gets me to the layout you see below. In addition I am trying to make a new worksheet based off of each section, but I will try to tackle that another time.

```
Sub SOFCMacro()

'Begins Macro Optimizations
   Application.ScreenUpdating = False
   Application.EnableEvents = False
   Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual
   Application.DisplayAlerts = False

'Declarations
   Dim Firstrow As Long
   Dim Lastrow As Long
   Dim Lrow As Long
 Dim rng As Range

'Renames Sheet1 and Make It an Object
  Set Main = ActiveSheet
  Main.Name = "BAR"

'Add and Name Worksheets
  Set WS1 = Sheets.Add
  WS1.Name = "SOFC"

'Clear Formatting
  Sheets("BAR").Activate
  With ActiveSheet
    .Cells.ClearFormats
  End With

***'Comma Diliminate Funding Information
  Sheets("Bar").Activate
  With ActiveSheet
    Set rng = .Range(rng, .Cells(.Rows.Count, rng.Column).End(xlUp))
    For i = Last To 1 Step -1
        If Not IsError(.vaule) Then
            ElseIf (cells(i, "F").value = "092000:"    and "Salaries:" Then cells(Cells, i, "A").value = (Cells(i, "F").Value) Like "20*"
            ElseIf .value = "092300:" and "Defender:" Then cells(Cells, i, "A").value = (Cells(i, "F").Value) Like "20*"
            ElseIf .value = "51140X:" and "Judiciary:" Then cells(Cells, i, "A").value = (Cells(i, "F").Value) Like "20*"
            ElseIf .value = "51140E:" and "Electronic:" Then cells(Cells, i, "A").value = (Cells(i, "F").Value) Like "20*"
    End if
End With***

'Copies Columns from Budget Availability Reports to SOFC Worksheet
   Sheets("BAR").Columns(1).Copy Destination:=Sheets("SOFC").Columns(4)
   Sheets("BAR").Columns(2).Copy Destination:=Sheets("SOFC").Columns(5)
   Sheets("BAR").Columns(3).Copy Destination:=Sheets("SOFC").Columns(6)
   Sheets("BAR").Columns(4).Copy Destination:=Sheets("SOFC").Columns(7)

'Deletes "Main Worksheet"
   Sheets("BAR").Delete

'Inserts Header Row
   Sheets("SOFC").Range("A2").EntireRow.Insert

'Add Headers to Sheet
   Sheets("SOFC").Range("A1").Value = "BBFY"
   Sheets("SOFC").Range("B1").Value = "EBFY"
   Sheets("SOFC").Range("C1").Value = "FUND"
   Sheets("SOFC").Range("D1").Value = "BUDGET ORG"
   Sheets("SOFC").Range("E1").Value = "BOC"
   Sheets("SOFC").Range("F1").Value = "BOC Name"
   Sheets("SOFC").Range("G1").Value = "ALLOTMENT"

'Deletes Unneeded Rows
   Sheets("SOFC").Activate
  With ActiveSheet
    Firstrow = .UsedRange.Cells(1).Row
    Lastrow = .UsedRange.Rows(.UsedRange.Rows.Count).Row
    For Lrow = Lastrow To Firstrow Step -1
        With .Cells(Lrow, "D")
            If Not IsError(.Value) Then
                ElseIf .Value = "Activity Type:" Then .EntireRow.Delete
                ElseIf .Value = "Activity:" Then .EntireRow.Delete
                ElseIf .Value = "AO Division:" Then .EntireRow.Delete
            End If
        End With
    Next Lrow
End With

 'Deletes Rows Based On Criteria
    Last = Cells(Rows.Count, "D").End(xlUp).Row
    For i = Last To 1 Step -1
      If (Cells(i, "D").Value) = "Fund:" Then
         'Cells(i, "A").EntireRow.ClearContents ' USE THIS TO CLEAR CONTENTS BUT NOT DELETE ROW

        ElseIf (Cells(i, "D").Value) = "Activity Type:" Then
            Cells(i, "A").EntireRow.Delete
        ElseIf (Cells(i, "D").Value) = "Activity:" Then
            Cells(i, "A").EntireRow.Delete
        ElseIf (Cells(i, "D").Value) = "AO Division:" Then
            Cells(i, "A").EntireRow.Delete
        ElseIf (Cells(i, "D").Value) = " Org Code" Then
            Cells(i, "A").EntireRow.Delete
        ElseIf (Cells(i, "F").Value) = "Org Code Subtotal:" Then
            Cells(i, "A").EntireRow.Delete
        ElseIf (Cells(i, "F").Value) = "AO Division Subtotal:" Then
            Cells(i, "A").EntireRow.Delete
        ElseIf (Cells(i, "F").Value) = "Activity Subtotal:" Then
            Cells(i, "A").EntireRow.Delete
        ElseIf (Cells(i, "F").Value) = "Activity Type Subtotal:" Then
            Cells(i, "A").EntireRow.Delete
        ElseIf (Cells(i, "F").Value) = "Fund Subtotal:" Then
            Cells(i, "A").EntireRow.Delete
'Change Values for Courts in Current Wave
        ElseIf (Cells(i, "F").Value) = "ARW - Arkansas Western" Then
            Cells(i, "A").EntireRow.Delete
        ElseIf (Cells(i, "F").Value) = "CAN - California Northern" Then
            Cells(i, "A").EntireRow.Delete
        ElseIf (Cells(i, "F").Value) = "GAS - Georgia Southern" Then
            Cells(i, "A").EntireRow.Delete
        ElseIf (Cells(i, "F").Value) = "MDX - Maryland" Then
            Cells(i, "A").EntireRow.Delete
        ElseIf (Cells(i, "F").Value) = "NDX - North Dakota" Then
            Cells(i, "A").EntireRow.Delete
        ElseIf (Cells(i, "F").Value) = "NYE - New York Eastern" Then
            Cells(i, "A").EntireRow.Delete
        ElseIf (Cells(i, "F").Value) = "ORX - Oregon" Then
            Cells(i, "A").EntireRow.Delete
        ElseIf (Cells(i, "F").Value) = "SDX - South Dakota" Then
            Cells(i, "A").EntireRow.Delete
'Change Values for Courts in Current Wave
        ElseIf (Cells(i, "F").Value) = "" Then
            Cells(i, "A").EntireRow.Delete
    Else
    End If
Next i

'Gets BBFY and Fund and Place Values in Correct Columns
'Last = Cells(Rows.Count, "D").End(xlUp).Row
   For i = Last To 1 Step -1
     If (Cells(i, "D").Value) = "Fund:" Then
         ElseIf (Cells(i, "F").Value) Like "20*" Then
         YearYo = Left(Cells(i, "20*"), 4)
         If Date Like "20*" Then
         Cells(i, "A").Value = Date
         End If
     Else

    End If
 Next i

'Gets Leading 0 for Fund Code
  Columns("C:C").Select
  Selection.NumberFormat = "000000"


End Sub
```

Comment: Creating a [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) may help you receive more help with your question.

Answer (score 0):

One suggestion, if your spreadsheet is consistent in the BOC column, then maybe that's the best place to start.

```
Dim i as Integer
Dim j as Integer
Dim LR as Long
LR = Cells(Sheets("NAME").Columns(6).Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row

For j = 1 to LR
For i = 1 to 3
If Cells(j,i)/Value="" Then
        Cells(j,i).Formula= 'come up with reference for the BOC Name
    Else:
    End If

Next i
Next j
```

It's not perfect and could probably be done better with a For Each (I'm not very good with those), but it could be at least a start.  This option doesn't find dynamic ranges to fill in the blank (e.g. dynamically define the big yellow block of squares and paste into them).  It just loops through all cells in the first 3 rows, til the end of the last row (used column F (Columns(6)) as is seems to be your only fully filled column).

If you want more specific to what goes into each cell:

```
Dim i as Integer
Dim LR as Long
LR = Cells(Sheets("NAME").Columns(6).Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row

For i = 1 to LR

If Cells(i,1)/Value="" Then
        Cells(i,1).Formula= "=Left(REF,4)'come up with reference for the BOC Name
        Cells(i,2).Formula= "=Left(Right(REF,6),11)
        Cells(i,3).Formula= "=Right(REF,3)
    Else:
    End If

Next i
```